# Connecting Office Word 7 to ODBC source in Win 7 Prof 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, ms-word, odbc, ms-office

> Microsoft Data Link Error - Test connection failed because of an error initializing provider. Unspecified error.

I have created a User DSN ODBC source using the Win 7 ODBC Data Source Administrator with the 64 bit MySQL ODBC 5.1 driver installed and get a 'Connection Successful' response when I test that in the  MySql Connector/ODBC Data Source Configuration panel.

Within Word I navigate to the Data Connection Wizard and choose ODBC DSN and click Next and then select the ODBC source created above, which then opens the Data Link Properties window with the 'Connection, tab active.

On selecting the correct Data Source name, entering username, entering password and clicking 'TEST CONNECTION', I get the above error message.

A similar procedure worked fine on a win XP Prof 32 bit laptop.

On 26th Feb, Bob had similar problem and suggested that leaving the PROVIDER blank solved the problem. If, within the Data Link Properties window, I activate the PROVIDER tab and attempt to select the blank at the bottom, I am told that a PROVIDER must be selected.

Advice on were I am going wrong or what else needs doing would be appreciated.

Comment: Have this problem resolved yet? How to fix?

Comment: same here, I have Win 7 64 and I've tried every version of the connector for windows(32/64) to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Had the exact same problem. Win7 x64 Pro. Excel 2007 and MySQL ODBC driver 5.2.2 x64.

I created an ODBC data source at Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources. Test connection OK and everythings fine.

Then I tried a connection with MS Excel. I navigate to the Data Connection Wizard and choose ODBC DSN and click Next and then select the ODBC source created above, which then opens the Data Link Properties window with the 'Connection, tab active. Conncetion Test fails and couldn't get it to work.

I FIXED this by installing ALSO the 32 bit version of the ODBC driver! After the 32 bit installation Excel ODBC DSN work correctly and gives me table data on the worksheet OK!

Comment: This helped me also when trying to connect database to Enterprise Architect application. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just have the same problem. My machine is Win7 x64. In ODBC, Test Connection Successful. But in the Excel don't.

Found that the way to fix is install the Connector 32 Bits version. This may because Ms.Office still in x86 and it cannot be able to connect to x64 drivers.